# Update attribute table by values from other layer

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, geometry, update

let's imagine that I have 2 different layers with geometry. Some objects from the first layer are "within" the second layer's objects. I'd like to update `firstLayer_value` in attribute table by value of attribute `secondLayer_value` from second layer for objects which are within. Till now I was using **refFunctions** plugin by creating new column with query: `geomwithin('layerName','columnName')` but it works super slow for many objects. Is there a faster way to do this?

My layers are in .shp format, In main line layer i got vectors which represents dykes or cuttings (2100 records) which goes through the roads, and second layer is 2m buffors of roads(22000 records). Now I need to create new column on my dykes layer which have value of the road's width. Its stored in attribute `width` on my buffors layer.

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location`?

Comment: @Erik thanks for answer, i just ran your suggested tool, but it seems to be same slow as refFunctions ;/ about 2 hours

Comment: Then let's imagine, you told us about the properties of your layers (size, number of features, details on features, number of attributes, etc) ;-)

Comment: well, i've updated my question a bit

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I am not proficient in terms of working with large data sets. I could hurl buzzwords at you and you'd be none the wiser. But it could be interesting, whether you need to do this regularly, or just once. In the second case you just could sit out the 2h and do something else in the meantime.

Comment: Unfortunately its a cyclic process, And similar calculations to this one are over 20, so thats why i dont want to spend that much time on this.

Comment: The only relationship between those 2 layers is the geometry `within` or do the layers share at least an attribute (e.g., an id)?